# Does this circuit include two level logic circuits?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I made the circuit below from the logic expression below.

> A'B' + A'C' + A'D + ABC

But, I was told to consider adding two level AND-OR and NAND-NAND logic circuits. I think the circuit below has them, but I'm not sure. Can I get a confirmation if I'm right? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/sum-of-products-form : this article instructs you on a 'two level logic' terminology. Consider also excluding simple inverters (triangles with circles) in favor of inverting inputs of logic elements

Comment: Is the question whether any (or all) of the elements in your circuit diagram are NAND?

Comment: I'm suppose to turn the logic expression into a circuit which is in the simplest form. They suggest us to consider including AND-OR and NAND-NAND logic circuits. I did the circuit but I'm not sure if it is in the simplest form.

Comment: `in the simplest form` Among others, there is *using the least number of (simple) gates*, *using least sum of inputs+outputs* and *least number of gates while avoiding all static/avoidable hazards*. I think your schematic fits the latter.